# Django 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

I am using social login in my Django app. So, I have added additional backends in my `settings.py` file.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth',
    'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',
```

]

I have also used `UserCreationForm` for signup,

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2' )
```

This is the views file,

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form  = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_pass = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=raw_pass)
            login(request,user,backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
            url = reverse('location:get_location')
            print("location_url ", url)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form':form})
```

Now, I get this error when i click signup button on my form,

```
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

at the line,

```
login(request,user,backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
```

Why so ?

I can see in my admin panel that user has been saved.

What is causing this error ? and how to solve it ?

EDIT -

```
Internal Server Error: /signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luvpreet/Envs/weather/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/luvpreet/Envs/weather/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
   File "/home/luvpreet/Envs/weather/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/luvpreet/Desktop/drf-vogo/weather/weather/pilot/views.py", line 45, in signup
    login(request,user,backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
  File "/home/luvpreet/Envs/weather/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 154, in login
     request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
  File "/home/luvpreet/Envs/weather/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 239, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: @Alasdair please check the stacktrace,  `from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You already have the user when you save the form, so you don't need to call `authenticate` since you already provide the backend when calling `login()`:

```
user = form.save()
login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
```

Answer (score 2):

Came here looking for this error. Our stack is django-oscar + wagtail. It turns out we removed `oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend` from our `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`. Putting it back solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The UserCreationForm() provides for both password and the password_confirmation fields.
Authentication fails in this case because you are trying to get "password" which does not exists, therefore returning user as None. 
If you print form.cleaned_data, you get a dictionary similar to this

`{'username': 'myuser', 'password1': 'pass1234', 'password2': 'pass1234'}`

Changing the raw_pass line should fix the issue:

`raw_pass = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')`

Answer (score 1):

Cause of Returning None While logging with created user from registration form , in DB it is checking specific user with encrypted password ,but we are saving password in text from  that is why if you give even correct username and password ,it is failing

Add below model backends in setting.py file

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

or pass backend to login function itself

```
login(request, username,password, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
```

import make_password function and pass password to it which is comming from registration form then it will save password into Db in encrypted form

`from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password`

`raw_pass = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
 raw_pass = make_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password'))`

Django=2.2.4

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you havent hashed the password. This worked for me. Try:

```
        user = userform.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue (using Django 2.2).

To fix I added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'` to settings.py above `MIDDLEWARE`.

From the [2.2 Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) on substituting a custom User model:

" Django allows you to override the default user model by providing a value for the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting that references a custom model: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'`. This dotted pair describes the name of the Django app (which must be in your INSTALLED_APPS), and the name of the Django model that you wish to use as your user model "

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem because I had customized authentication and was passing wrong arguments in `authenticate()`

You did not share your custom user model, but it could be that you are using email as the `USERNAME_FIELD`.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

So in the relevant view, you will need to pass email (and not username) as an argument to `authenticate()`

```
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        login(request, user)
    ...
```