# ValueError: The view accounts.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. When attempting to register user

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

When attempting to register a user (after changing my project from default user model to custom user model) I get this value error. The following is my View.

```
def register(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        email= request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(
            request,
            email=email,
            password=password,
        )
        login(request, user)

        return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
else:
    form = RegisterForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)
```

Comment: Read your code through, and think about what happens if the submitted form is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
def register(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method =='POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email= request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(
                request,
                email=email,
                 password=password,
            )
            login(request, user)

            return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)
```

Comment: After changing the code to that, I'm getting this error,  ''AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta''

Comment: the full traceback, the line, the view

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284664/django-anonymoususer-object-has-no-attribute-meta/46284838#46284838) for a solution to the attribute error.