# Django: no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'

Tags: django, model, natural-key

i currently try the implement my very own user model. Therefor i created a new app "accounts". But each time when i try to create anew user i get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

accounts - models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)



#User Model Manager
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Error: The User you want to create must have an username, try again')

        user = self.model(
            user=self.normalize_username(username),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, username, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given username and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given username and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    #User fields
    user = models.CharField(verbose_name='username',max_length=30,unique=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True)
    pubpgp = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    #Account typs
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that's built in.

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] # Username & Password are required by default.

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their Username ;)
        return self.user

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their Username address
        return self.user
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        """Does the user have a specific permission?"""
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        """Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"""
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        """Is the user a member of staff?"""
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        """Is the user a admin member?"""
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        """Is the user active?"""
        return self.active

    objects = UserManager()
```

After that i jumpt back to settings.py and added the custom user model to my acctual blog application:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

and i also added

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'accounts',
...   
]
```

All this user model/django stuff is a bit new to me and i have no idea what the error "AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'" means.

Thanks :D

Comment: How are you trying to create user ? Via admin ui?
Add `manager = UserManager` in your User model and then try creating the user.

Comment: @Venom add `objects = UserManager()` to you custom `User`

Comment: @Yusef BH: solved something again ;)
New error see above.

Comment: May be some flow in your login/authentication logic in `view`, need more detail for clarity

Comment: @Venom check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284664/django-anonymoususer-object-has-no-attribute-meta) it might help, if not consider posting your `view` code

Comment: @ Yusef BH: See: https://gitlab.venom.one/venom/Quickblog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: AttributeError: 'UserManager' object has no attribute 'normalize_username'**

`normalize_username` belongs to `AbstractBaseUser`, you can **try the code below.**

In `signup` view, when you save the form you already get the user (`form.save()`). Because the reason from authentication is to verify a set of credentials and getting the user **(but we already have the user)**

In this line: `user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)`, the `authenticate` method takes `request` as the first argument, so it should be: `user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=raw_password)`, therefore you got the Error **'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'**.

**Try:**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('post_list')
```

**Edit UserManager:**

**Reaname all created users to some other name (ex. `my_user`) because you have tow varibales with the same name (the `USERNAME_FIELD` and the user created)**

Here is the signature of `create_user` and `create_superuser`

`create_user(*username_field*, password=None, **other_fields)
create_superuser(*username_field*, password, **other_fields)`

They take the `USERNAME_FIELD` as the first argument, and yours is `user`

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, user, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username and password.
        """
        if not user:
            raise ValueError('Error: The User you want to create must have an username, try again')

        my_user = self.model(
            user=self.model.normalize_username(user),
        )

        my_user.set_password(password)
        my_user.save(using=self._db)
        return my_user

    def create_staffuser(self, user, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given username and password.
        """
        my_user = self.create_user(
            user,
            password=password,
        )
        my_user.staff = True
        my_user.save(using=self._db)
        return my_user

    def create_superuser(self, user, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given username and password.
        """
        my_user = self.create_user(
            user,
            password=password,
        )
        my_user.staff = True
        my_user.admin = True
        my_user.save(using=self._db)
        return my_user
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: @Venom your welcome, the `authenticate` method takes request as first argument see the edited answer.

Comment: @Venom check out the answer now.

Comment: now i get AttributeError: 'UserManager' object has no attribute 'normalize_username' ...

Comment: @Venom check out the answer now.

Comment: Okay my fault also was that i got user=self.normalize_username(username),
and normalize_username was not used by me :( anyways. problem solved! Merci :D

Comment: @Venom you can use `normalize_username`, but this way  `user = self.model.normalize_username(user)`

Comment: But what do i actually normalize here xD ?

Comment: @Venom you normalize `user` field, and [here is what it does from django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.normalize_username)