# how to solve 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' error in django

Tags: django

I am trying to make a login interface. but after submitting form this error '

> AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

occurs. how to solve this issue? I can not find any solution. i have also tried to get data using `form._cleaned_data.get()` method. still it does not work.

my forms.py

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from diabetes.models import UserSignupModel


class UserSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=60,help_text="add a valid email address",required=False)
    name=forms.CharField(max_length=15,help_text="add a valid name")
    age=forms.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        model=UserSignupModel
        fields=('email','name',"username",'age',"password1","password2")



class UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(label="password",widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model=UserSignupModel
        fields=("email","password")
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager



class SignUpManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email,age,name, username, password=None):
        #if not email:
            #raise ValueError("insert user")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("insert username")
        if not name:
            raise ValueError("insert name")
        if not age:
            raise ValueError("insert age")
        user = self.model(
           email=self.normalize_email(email),
           username=username,
           age=age,
           name=name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email,name,age,username, password):

        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password,
            age=age,
            name=name,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class UserSignupModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60,blank=True,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','name','age']
    objects = SignUpManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
#migrate --run-syncdb in case no work
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate,logout
from diabetes.forms import UserSignupForm,UserLoginForm


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'diabetes/home.html')

def signupuser(request):
    context={}
    if request.POST:
        form=UserSignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email=form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            name=form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            age=form.cleaned_data.get('age')
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')

            account=authenticate(email=email,password=raw_password,name=name,age=age,username=username)
            login(request,account)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            context["reg_form"]=form

    else:
        form = UserSignupForm()
        context["reg_form"] = form
    return render (request,'diabetes/signupuser.html',context)


def logoutuser(request):

    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

def loginuser(request):

    if request.method=="POST":
        form=UserLoginForm(request.POST)

        password=request.POST["password"]
        email=request.POST["email"]
        account=authenticate(password=password,email=email)
        login(request,account)
        redirect("home")

    else:
        form=UserLoginForm()

        return render(request,"diabetes/loginuser.html",{'form':form})
```

my loginuser.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `signupuser` method in your `views.py` remove the line for `authenticate`. You have the account when you save the form. Change `form.save()` to `account = form.save()` and you are good to go. Check this answer for more information: [anonymoususer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284664/django-anonymoususer-object-has-no-attribute-meta)

Comment: My bad, do you have `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in your settings file? The problem may cause for wrong authenticate backend as answered in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57619949/2474573

Comment: Did this answer help you on the error, @imtinan? If it helps, please accept the answer to help others who visit this page later.