# how to make login authentication with custom user model in django

Tags: django

i have made a custom user model. signup and logout is working fine. but i have made a login form using that model. but whenever i try to submit the form ,after authentication it is supposed to redirect me to home page. but unfortunately it does not authenticate and redirect me to login page repeatedly. how should i solve this?

my models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager



class SignUpManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email,age,name, username, password=None):
        #if not email:
            #raise ValueError("insert user")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("insert username")
        if not name:
            raise ValueError("insert name")
        if not age:
            raise ValueError("insert age")
        user = self.model(
           email=self.normalize_email(email),
           username=username,
           age=age,
           name=name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email,name,age,username, password):

        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password,
            age=age,
            name=name,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class UserSignupModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60,blank=True,null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','name','age']
    objects = SignUpManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
#migrate --run-syncdb in case no work
```

my forms.py

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from diabetes.models import UserSignupModel
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate,logout


class UserSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(max_length=60,help_text="add a valid email address",required=False)
    name=forms.CharField(max_length=15,help_text="add a valid name")
    age=forms.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        model=UserSignupModel
        fields=('email','name',"username",'age',"password1","password2")



class UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(label="password",widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model=UserSignupModel
        fields=("email","password")

        def clean(self):
            if self.is_valid():

                email=self.cleaned_data('email')
                password=self.cleaned_data('password')

                if not authenticate(email=email,password=password):
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid LOGIN")
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate,logout
from diabetes.forms import UserSignupForm,UserLoginForm



# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'diabetes/home.html')

def signupuser(request):
    context={}
    if request.POST:
        form=UserSignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email=form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            name=form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            age=form.cleaned_data.get('age')
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')

            account=authenticate(email=email,password=raw_password,name=name,age=age,username=username)
            login(request,account)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            context["reg_form"]=form

    else:
        form = UserSignupForm()
        context["reg_form"] = form
    return render (request,'diabetes/signupuser.html',context)


def logoutuser(request):

    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')

def loginuser(request):
    context={}

    if request.method=="POST":

        form=UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            password=request.POST["password"]
            email=request.POST["email"]
            user=authenticate(email=email,password=password)
            if user:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect("home")

    else:
        form=UserLoginForm()


    context['form']=form
    return render(request,"diabetes/loginuser.html",context)
```

my loginuser.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <p>

        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field}}
        {% if field.help_text %}
             <small>{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
         {% for error in field.errors %}
             <strong>{{ error }}</strong>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if form.non_field_errors %}
             <small>{{ form.non_field_errors}}</small>
        {% endif %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit">SUBMIT</input>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to solve 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '\_meta' error in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61858749/how-to-solve-anonymoususer-object-has-no-attribute-meta-error-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, is it possible that u just forgott to define the redirect url after login? 
Can u please check this, im not sure!

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/your-path'
```